# MacOS able to access data without password

Tags: authentication, passwords, macos

On a Mac, one can go into recovery mode by turning off the Mac and clicking `Command R` while turning it on. Then, by typing `resetpassword` into Terminal, one is able to reset the password without entering the old password.

Why is this not considered a security flaw? It doesn't seem to lock out data, so I can easily go into a someone's laptop, reset the password, and see all their data.

Comment: Your user account password is changed, but you cannot access Keychain or FileVault.

Comment: @Linny That's assuming FileVault is turned on

Comment: It's just as easy on GNU+Linux and fairly easy on Windows. This is why full disk encryption is important.

Comment: What makes you think it's *not* considered a security flaw?

Comment: @MechMK1 it seems intentional - not some workaround or anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the disk is not encrypted, there is simply no way to prevent such attacks. Sure, you can make it slightly more cumbersome by requiring the attacker to insert the disk into another computer to modify files, but this is a trivial task that can be accomplished in five minutes.

The antidote to this is encrypting the disk volumes. This effectively blocks access to data, even if you're able to read and write the raw disk volume.